# Ubuntu 12.04 fresh install comes with xorg 1.13

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, catalyst

I have an ATI-Radeon HD4500 and because AMD doesn´t yet support the new Xorg Version 1.13 for the Catalyst-Legacy Driver I decided to make a clean Install of Ubuntu 12.04 which I thought should come with Xorg 1.12!

But surprisingly after Installation Xorg -version tells me that I have 1.13 installed...
Does anybody has an Idea how this is possible? And what should I do now, I need the AMD-Driver because my Laptop gets insanely hot with the opensource driver...

Unfortunately this [Link](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html) doesn´t help in my case, apt-get keeps telling me

[Unable to locate package fglrx-legacy]

Hopefully somebody can help me solve this, I can´t really use my Laptop without the Driver...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this to be the case when trying to get the sis 671 video driver to work. I  installed Mint 14 and then Ubuntu 12.10 and couldn't get it to work. After reading numerous posts on forums I installed 12.04 which was definitely supposed to work but it didn't. More reading lead me to realize Xorg 1.13 is the problem which now appears to be what gets shipped with Ubuntu 12.04.2. I have gone back a version Ubuntu 12.04.1 which uses X.Org X Server 1.11.3 and bingo the driver works!

I found Ubuntu 12.04.1 here. 
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily switch to Xorg 1.11 in Ubuntu 12.04.2.

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-all